# box2D and libgdx: Attach ParticleEffect to Body

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Hello I am a newbie with libgdx, my question is: how could I add a Particleeffect to a Body that is moving? I searched about the matter and I didnt find anything related to it.

I have the following code to add my ball:

```
public Body createThrowedBall(float x, float y) {

    Gdx.app.log("createThrowedBall", "("+x+","+y+")");

    BodyDef ballDef = new BodyDef();
    ballDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    ballDef.position.set(x,y);

    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(5.5f);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef= new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0f;
    fixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = -1;

    Body body = world.createBody(ballDef);
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    shape.dispose();


    // note the massive impulse vector

    body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 5500), new Vector2(x,camera.viewportHeight), false);

    return body;
}
```

That draws a simple circle shape that is throwed up. I want to add like a fire effect burning during the throw ( I did it with the Particle Editor) but I dont know how to attach it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it adding the ParticleEffect to he body and before rendering the effect in render function:

```
    public Body createThrowedBall(float x, float y) {

    Gdx.app.log("createThrowedBall", "("+x+","+y+")");

    BodyDef ballDef = new BodyDef();
    ballDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    ballDef.position.set(x,y);

    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(5.5f);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef= new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0f;
    fixtureDef.filter.groupIndex = -1;

    Body body = world.createBody(ballDef);
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    ParticleEffect effect = new ParticleEffect();
    effect.load(Gdx.files.internal("effects/ball_in_fire.p"), Gdx.files.internal("img"));
    effect.setPosition((x+camera.viewportWidth/2)*10, (y+camera.viewportHeight/2)*10);
    effect.start();     
    body.setUserData(effect);

    shape.dispose();


    // note the massive impulse vector

    body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 5500), new Vector2(x,camera.viewportHeight), false);

    return body;
}
```

in render:

```
    public void render(float delta)
{
...
        game.batch.begin();
        //imageBackground.draw(game.batch, 1.0f);
        Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
        world.getBodies(bodies);
        for(int i=0;i<bodies.size;i++)
        {
            ParticleEffect effect = (ParticleEffect)bodies.get(i).getUserData();
            if(effect != null)
            {
                effect.setPosition((bodies.get(i).getPosition().x+camera.viewportWidth/2)*10, (bodies.get(i).getPosition().y+camera.viewportHeight/2)*10);
                effect.draw(game.batch,delta);
            }

        }

        game.batch.end();
}
```

**NOTE:** I calculated the position of the effect because the ParticleEffect need the x,y of the screen and the ball needs the x,y of the camera.